# Saving text from a UITextView into NSUserDefaults the same way a UITextFIeld is saved in a Notes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, save, uitextview

I am new to Objective-C, but have some programming knowledge. So I followed Todd Perkin's tutorial on making a notes application on Lynda.com. To get more familiar with Objective-C, I am wanting to add things to this notes app to learn more, but I'm kind of stuck.

Currently, the notes app is built in a Master Detail application template. So there is a Table View in the MasterDetailView controller, and a detail view in the DetailViewController. When a user taps the add button, it segues to the Detail controller and there is a UITextField that you type into and when you click Back, it saves that UITextField to NSUserDefaults, and thats what is used to populate the cell in the Table View.

So basically, what I have done is add a UITextView for another spot in the Detail View. But I can't figure out the best way to save that the same way the title of the note is saved. Obviously, each one needs to be different for each note. Here are the classes and the code I'm using:

MasterDetailController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

MasterDetailController.m

```
@interface MasterViewController () {
NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self makeObjects];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =         @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"Logo-Small.png"]];


UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self makeObjects];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)makeObjects{
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[Data getAllNotes]allKeys]];

//Sorts notes by order they were created in
[_objects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDate * obj1, NSDate * obj2) {
    return [obj2 compare:obj1];
}];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{

NSString *key=[[NSDate date]description];
[Data setNote:kDefaultText forKey:key];
[Data setCurrentKey:key];
[_objects insertObject:key atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:kDetailView sender:self];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [[Data getAllNotes]objectForKey:object];
return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [Data removeNoteForKey:[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [Data saveNote];
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
}
*/

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
}
}

@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *rTView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tView;


@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Data.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;
    [Data setCurrentKey:_detailItem];
    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}
}

- (void)configureView
{
NSString *currentNote = [[Data getAllNote]objectForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
if (![currentNote isEqualToString:kDefaultText]) {
    self.tView.text = currentNote;

}
else {
    self.tView.text = @"";
}

//Brings up the keyboard when you go into a note
//[self.tView becomeFirstResponder];
}


-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
if (![self.tView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [Data setNoteForCurrentKey:self.tView.text];
} else{
    [Data removeNoteForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
}

[Data saveNotes];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self configureView];
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
self.rTView.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}


@end
```

And the Data model that was in the tutorial:

Data.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define kDefaultText @"New Note"
#define kAllNote @"notes"
#define kDetailView @"showDetail"


@interface Data : NSObject

+(NSMutableDictionary *)getAllNotes;
+(void)setCurrentKey: (NSString *)key;
+(NSString *)getCurrentKey;
+(void)setNoteForCurrentKey:(NSString*)note;
+(void)setNote:(NSString*)note forKey:(NSString*)key;
+(void)removeNoteForKey:(NSString*)key;
+(void)saveNotes;

@end
```

Data.m

```
@implementation Data

static NSMutableDictionary *allNotes=nil;
static NSString *currentKey=nil;

+(NSMutableDictionary *)getAllNotes{
if (allNotes == nil) {
    allNotes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:kAllNotes]];
}
return allNotes;

}
+(void)setCurrentKey: (NSString *)key{
currentKey = key;

}
+(NSString *)getCurrentKey{
return currentKey;

}
+(void)setNoteForCurrentKey:(NSString*)note{
[self setNote:note forKey:currentKey];

}
+(void)setNote:(NSString*)note forKey:(NSString*)key{
[allNotes setObject:note forKey:key];

}
+(void)removeNoteForKey:(NSString*)key{
[allNotes removeObjectForKey:key];

}
+(void)saveNotes{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:allNotes forKey:kAllNotes];
}

@end
```

Phew. Sorry. That's a lot of code. So the tView is the value that's being saved. I've defined the UITextView as rTView. But I don't know how to make that text view save for each note like it's doing for the UITextFIeld.

I would appreciate any help. Please.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that now you will have more attributes to be saved for each node, and they should come together in a collection like NSArray, NSDictionary etc. However, to answer your question will take a lot of time, I am going to give some tips only:

You need to change your Model class first, to contain all the properties you need.
In DetailViewController.h, you need to change the configureView method, this line:

```
NSString *currentNote = [[Data getAllNote]objectForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
```

should be like:

NSDictionary *currentNote = [[Data getAllNote] objectForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];

and probably something like this:

if (![[currentNote objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:kDefaultTitle]) {
     self.tView.text = [currentNote objectForKey:@"title"];
     self.rView.text = [currentNote objectForKey:@"description"];
   } else {
     self.tView.text = @"";
     self.rView.text = @"";
   }

Also, viewDidDisappear should be changed in that file.

My advice is to change the Model first, and then analyze step by step each method in the View Controllers, and you will figure it out.